# Meditation to music producing massive emotions and physical sensations?

Tags: meditation

Please forgive me if this may seem out of place.

Recently I've started meditating using Headspace. After a session I felt good and listed to a few of my favorite songs while continuing to lie down with eyes closed.

The mediation combined with songs afterwards (especially at a few key times in the songs) has given me unbelievable positive emotions. I get full body goosebumps, and my eyelids, which are closed, start uncontrollably twitching. It almost feels like I'm going to lift out of my body.

Is any part of this normal? It sometimes seems scary, but I push through.

My question is: where do I go from here? I want to follow this thread and learn more, wherever it goes to hone and elevate from here.

The closest thing I've read that this resembles the concept of 'piti', which sounded like a massive dam busting.